# searching for a specific column and performing sorting and filtering using excel vba macos

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have 2 workbooks. Workbook 1 and workbook 2. I am performing sorting and filtering in workbook 1 from workbook 2.

```
Sub filter_5PKT1_rows()

    Dim file_name  As String
    Dim sheet_name As String


   file_name = "C:\Users\Desktop\pocket setter excel\workbook 1.xlsm"  


 Dim wb As Workbook, mysh As Worksheet

 Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file_name)

    Set mysh = wb.Sheets(1) 



    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long



 Set My_Range = Range("A1:L" & LastRow(wb.ActiveSheet))



 My_Range.Parent.Select

 If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    wb.ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False



   My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("5PKT Men's", "5PKT Women's", "5PKT Short"), Operator:=xlFilterValues





   My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Band 10", "Band 13", "Band 17", "Band 19"), Operator:=xlFilterValues



  Range("J1") = "PSD"
   Columns("A:L").sort key1:=Range("J2"), _
      order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes




    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

This works perfectly when the column headers in workbook 1 are constant.

Workbook 1 will be updated and emailed to me weekly. When this updating occurs new columns are added or column positions may change.

If this happens how can i perform my sorting and filtering since i cannot refer by column/field number.

for example AutoFilter Field:=4,

field 4 in this instance is a column header with name product type
the next time this workbook is updated, it could change to some thing else

Is there a way to find a specific column header, maybe using Like statement, and perform the sorting and filtering?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim col As Integer
col = 1
Do Until Range("A1").offset(0, col - 1).Value = "targetColumnHeader"
    col = col + 1

    ' if the column name changed or is misspelled,
    ' want to loop forever, put a limit:
    If col > 200 Then 
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Then later use that col value:

```
... Field:=col, ...
```

There's probably a cleaner way to write that loop.  That's just the first idea I had.

Comment: How do i search for a column header like "product type"?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, replace "targetColumnHeader" with "product type".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find() to locate your headers:

```
Dim f as Range, hdr As String

hdr = "*product*type*" 'can use wildcards here....

Set f = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:=hdr, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not f Is Nothing Then
    My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=f.Column, Criteria1:=Array("5PKT Men's", _
                                       "5PKT Women's", "5PKT Short"), _
                                        Operator:=xlFilterValues
Else
    MsgBox "Couldn't find header ' & hdr & ' !", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
```